# How to insert data using entity_save function in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am working on Drupal 7, in this I have added one field column into my database table using `hook_update_N()` function and run `update.php` but my `entity_get_info` not updating that field into base table SQL list. I have cleared all caches also but no use.

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

So you have to make a schema_alter into .install file to add into registry your new column .

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7.x

Also you can run again your updater after decrease column schema version into system table if field was not created :

```
update system set schema_version = 700N-1 where name = 'your_module'
```

Hope it will bring some help